# Data binding does not update ui element

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have trouble getting a binding done using the WPF.

I have a model class which is similar to this:

```
public class DataModel 
{
     private double _temp;

     public double Temperature 
     {
        set
        {
            _temp= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Temperature");
        }

        get { return this._temp; }
     }
 }
```

This model is derived from a class BaseDataModel

```
public abstract class BaseDataModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);

        }
     }
 }
```

I now have a list of DataModel objects in another class called DataViewModel, the List is named "Values". In a class above that class I have an UserControl that needs to de dynamically created at runtime, therefore binding is done in code behind like this :

somewhere above the list:

```
DataViewModel model = new DataViewModel();
```

and the binding itself:

```
curbinding = new Binding();
curbinding.Source = model.Values;
curbinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Temperature");
curbinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, curbinding);
```

I know that PropertyChanged is fired, but the value of the text box is not updated. I just can't figure out why? When I create the bindig the first time, the text of the text box is updated, but when I change the value of Temperature, nothing happens.
Did I not think of something?

I have to say, that the application has a lot of other classes and is more complex, but as I said, the value is updated once, and never again.

Comment: exactly where do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I am stupid ... I just foud out that I accedentally deleted that part and never even thought about it again... the soloution was to derive from INotifyPropertyChanged like this: BaseDataModel:INotifyPropertyChanged

thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't read the comments I simply forgot to implement INotifyPropertyChanged ...